# Como posso detectar e alertar que um determinado usuário está enviando muitas mensagens seguidas?

Tags: php, mysql, chat, flood

Em um sala de chat, como posso detectar e alertar que um determinado usuário do sistema está enviando muitas mensagens seguidas (*flood*)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sugiro guardar na sessão a data em que a mensagem foi enviada e um contador de mensagens. Se o usuário enviar outra mensagem, compare a data com a que está armazenada na sessão, se a diferença de tempo for curta, incremente um contador na sessão.

Se este contador chegar em um limite (ex: 3 mensagens) recuse os próximos requests até que um certo tempo tenha passado.

Para salvar o tempo do ultimo post

```php
$_SESSION["LastPost"] = time();
```

Para comparar o tempo do post

```php
// se o post foi feito novamente nos últimos 10 segundos
if (isset($_SESSION["LastPost"])
    && $_SESSION["LastPost"] <= (time() - 10))
{
    if (!isset($_SESSION["PostCount"]))
        $_SESSION["PostCount"] = 0;

    $_SESSION["PostCount"] += 1;
}
```

E para verificar se o usuário atingiu o limite de posts por segundo

```php
if (isset($_SESSION["PostCount"]) && $_SESSION["PostCount"] == 3)
{
    // você pode setar uma trava
    $_SESSION["LockPost"] = time() + 60;
}
```

Se a trava existir ignore o request.

```php
if (isset($_SESSION["LockPost"]) && $_SESSION["LockPost"] >= time())
{
    // bloqueado, ignore
}
else if (isset($_SESSION["LockPost"]))
{
    // o tempo de bloqueio passou
    // zere todas as variáveis da sessão
    unset($_SESSION["LockPost"]);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Boa resposta, mas 3  mensagens a cada 10 segundos é muito pouco, pois tem gente que consegue digitar 3 mensagens em pouco mais de um segundo... :)

Comment: Além disso, por questões de usabilidade, seria interessante **também** fazer um bloqueio redundante no *client* do *chat* para que o usuário saiba o que está acontecendo. Se ele tentar burlar, aí sim o servidor vai ignorar.

Comment: Boa observação, evitar _roundtrips_ é sempre uma boa.

Comment: No meu caso, quando o servidor detectar flood, ele vai inserir uma mensagem privada no tabela de chat, que apenas o autor do flood verá, alertando o ocorrido.

Comment: Seria legal comparar se as 3 mensagens tem textos parecidos, para ai sim detectar o flood, pois um usuario também pode digitar rápido.